# How can i communicate btn two SWF using LocalConnection methode (flash8)

Tags: flash

How can i communicate btn two SWF using LocalConnection methode (flash8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with this code:

```
var id:String = "CLIENT";

var textfield = _root.createTextField("txt", 0, 0, 0, 550, 400);
textfield.text += "waiting...\n";

var receiver:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

receiver.recieveText = function(text:String)
{
    textfield.text += "received... " + text + "\n";
};

receiver.connect("connection");

function sendData()
{
    var sender:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    var text = "hello from " + id;
    sender.send("connection", "recieveText", text);
    textfield.text += "sending... " + text + "\n";
}

_root.onMouseDown = function()
{
    sendData();
}
```

Publish it, and open it twice.

the things you can change and what are important are `.connect()` and `.send()`. Otherwise I think everything speaks for itself.

Hope this helps, feel free to ask if you have more questions.